# I can't sign in to Linkedin account because my email address is no good anymore

Tags: linkedin, account-recovery

It's been a year since I used Linkedin, and my email address is no longer available because I cancelled my GoDaddy account, which hosted that email address.

How can I reach Linkedin customer service to change my email to my current email address (which is the secondary email address of my Linkedin account)?

When I try, it wants me to Sign in, but I forgot my password and reset password doesn't work.

My phone# associated with my Linkedin account is still the same # since 1995.